# Sankey Plot not Showing in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram, holoviews

I'm pretty sure my code is fine, btu I can't generate a plot of a simple Sankey Chart. Maybe something is off with the code, not sure. Here's what I have now. Can anyone see a problem with this?

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as pex
hv.extension('bokeh')

data = [['TMD','TMD Create','Sub-Section 1',17],['TMD','TMD Create','Sub-Section 1',17],['C4C','Customer Tab','Sub-Section 1',10],['C4C','Customer Tab','Sub-Section 1',10],['C4C','Customer Tab','Sub-Section 1',17]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Source','Target','Attribute','Value'])
df

source = df["Source"].values.tolist()
target = df["Target"].values.tolist()
value = df["Value"].values.tolist()
labels = df["Attribute"].values.tolist()

import plotly.graph_objs as go

#create links
link = dict(source=source, target=target, value=value, 
color=["turquoise","tomato"] * len(source))

#create nodes
node = dict(label=labels, pad=15, thickness=5)

#create a sankey object
chart = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node, arrangement="snap")

#build a figure
fig = go.Figure(chart)
fig.show()
```

I am trying to follow the basic example shown in the link below.

https://python.plainenglish.io/create-a-sankey-diagram-in-python-e09e23cb1a75

Comment: Change `source` and `target` to a list of a indices that correspond to the `labels`

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mentioning two different packages, and both need different solutions. I don't know which you perefer, so I explain both.

#### Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Source':['a','a','b','b'],
    'Target':['c','d','c','d'],
    'Value': [1,2,3,4]
})
>>> df
  Source Target  Value
0      a      c      1
1      a      d      2
2      b      c      3
3      b      d      4
```

This is a very basic DataFrame with only 4 transitions.

#### Holoviews/Bokeh

With holoviews it is very easy to plot a sanky diagram, because it takes the DataFrame as it is and gets the labels by the letters in the `Source` and `Target` column.

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

sankey = hv.Sankey(df)
sankey.opts(width=600, height=400)
```

This is created with holoviews 1.15.4 and bokeh 2.4.3.

[image: sanky with holoviews]

#### Plotly

For plotly it is not so easy, because plotly wants numbers instead of letters in the `Source` and `Target` column. Therefor we have to manipulate the DataFrame first before we can create the figure.

Here I collect all different labels and replace them by a unique number.

```
unique_labels = set(list(df['Source'].unique()) + list(df['Target'].unique()))
mapper = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(unique_labels)}
df['Source'] = df['Source'].map(mapper)
df['Target'] = df['Target'].map(mapper
>>> df
   Source  Target  Value
0       0       2      1
1       0       3      2
2       1       2      3
3       1       3      4
```

Afterwards I can create the dicts which plotly takes. I have to set the lables by hand and the length of the arrays have to match.

```
source = df["Source"].values.tolist()
target = df["Target"].values.tolist()
value = df["Value"].values.tolist()

#create links
link = dict(source=source, target=target, value=value, color=["turquoise","tomato"] * 2)

#create nodes
node = dict(label=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], pad=15, thickness=5)

#create a sankey object
chart = go.Sankey(link=link, node=node, arrangement="snap")

#build a figure
fig = go.Figure(chart)
fig.show()
```

I used plotly 5.13.0.

[image: sanky with ploty]

Comment: That works! Thanks for the help here!! I found this site to be a great resource as well.

https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/data-science/how-to-plot-sankey-diagram-in-python-jupyter-notebook-holoviews-and-plotly

Comment: To use the latsest version of `bokeh` you have to update `panel` to 1.0 or higher and `holoviews` to 0.16 or higher as well.